# url redirection/mapping of the same java web application to multiple sub-domains

Tags: tomcat, apache2

I've a domain, say www.domain.com. And I've developed a java web application, say jwa. Now I want to install the same app for different clients using subdomains, what is the best solution possible?

something like "client1.domain.com" points to "client1" (renamed jwa)

I know we can get client1.domain.com/client1/ but client1 twice isn't good. or at least Can we get client1.domain.com/jwa/, without have multiple tomcat instances? btw, I'm running apache http server on the same server and using "proxy_module" for java/tomcat apps

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You dont need multiple Tomcat instances - you can point multiple clients across multiple subdomains to use the same web app

BUT be sure that this fits with your business use case - i.e. do you actually *want multiple instances of the webapp* running, or a can single instance serve all your clients.

I'm referring to the branding/logo/shared data/look-and-feel etc - is that common across all clients?

Lets assume it is.

With an Apache configured, the right way is to use `VirtualHost` directives along with mod_proxy.

A configuration like this on the Apache side should work - create one per subdomain, and point the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to the Tomcat web app

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName client1.domain.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /jwa http://client1.domain.com:8080/jwa
  ProxyPassReverse /jwa http://client1.domain.com:8080/jwa
</VirtualHost>
```

**Related Reading**

Apache docs [have lots of examples of VirtualHost configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html)

There is also a solution without Apache httpd, you can configure Host entires within Tomcat server.xml but Apache is a better place to manage your domain URLs

Comment: Thanks for the response, but different clients have different look-and-feel. Also, I do not want to show them /jwa in the url, but instead I would say client1.domain.com and it should point to client1.domain.com/jwa internally. (because domain itself is the web app name)

Comment: @user237865: Yes, that can be done. You have to set /jwa as the default web app for each domain within Tomcat, then it will not be shown in the URL. See my earlier answer on how to achieve that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708077/how-do-you-map-a-sub-domain-to-a-webapp-on-tomcat-6-including-the-root-webapp/3708876#3708876. In your case you will need a different copy of /jwa webapp for each client, something like jwaclient1, jwaclient2 etc since you need differnt functionality as you said.

Comment: Jose, I tried what you said: 
In apache http.conf >> 
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName client1.domain.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://client1.domain.com:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://client1.domain.com:8080/

</VirtualHost>

In tomcat server.xml
     <Host name="client1.domain.com" appBase="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/">
       <Context path="" docBase="/client1"/>
     </Host>
...... but still when I try client1.domain.com it is giving 404 error, any suggestions.

Comment: Does client1.domain.com:8080 directly hit to Tomcat serve your /jwa app? First try to resolve that, then you should check from Apache

Comment: Jose: I've tried this <Host name="client1.domain.com" appBase="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/client1">
       <Context path="" docBase="" />
 </Host>  , I'm able to see the index.jsp in the webcontent so client1.domain.com is recognising. But I've a folder admin (admin module) inside that I'm using few files from root as /common/includes/header.jsp It says "File "/common/includes/meta.jsp" not found" - Jasper Exception. Any suggestions why the error and how to fix it, Thanks.

Comment: Thats a completely different problem, so ask a new question.