# Subdomains, nginx and godaddy

Tags: nginx, subdomain

Here are the preconditions:

- I've registered domain `example.com` in godaddy.
- I run a Tomcat on `8080` port with a couple of applications. 8080 port is hidden to the world.
- I want to map `subdomain.example.com` to `server:8080/subdomain`. I want it be possible to do similar mappings (`subdomain2.example.com` to `server:8080/anotherContext`, for example) in the future.
- `example.com` should be mapped to `server:8080/mainPageApp`
- All other applications should be accesible via their context: `example.com/app` -> `server:8080/app`.

For now, I've only configured godaddy (I do not know if this is good):

[image: Godaddy domain config]

Can you help me with nginx config for this case? Here is mine, but it sends infinite redirects:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/subdomain;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I got this work. Not sure the solution is correct but:

First I need to setup a subdomain in Tomcat. [Here is the answer I was inspired with.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3708876/750510)

```
<Host name="subdomain.example.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="subdomain" />
</Host>
```

Then, configure nginx with:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        root   /path/to/domain/root;
        index  index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://subdomain.example.com:8080;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Domain config remains as in the question - it is good.

And finally I just put `subdomain.war` to the `webapp` directory of my Tomcat and it works like a charm!

Comment: moving forward, you can put the `proxy_set_header` into their own file (`proxy.conf`), and just include that as a macro in each location block.

Comment: you can also configure godaddy with a * for a wildcard dns that points every subdomain to your ip address.  that's really useful testing.  a final dumb trick is that , if this is a local box or you need some sort of local test , you can configure dns at godaddy to point to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Wow! The last trick is cool. I used `etc/hosts` file for this.

Comment: yeah - it works well if you're dealing with Twitter/Facebook oAuth.  You can just create alternate 'testing' API keys on each that point to 'localdev.domain.com' , set that to 127.0.0.1 on godaddy, and then your entire team can handle that without needing to deal with hosts.  (which gets annoying because you *always* forget to deactivate something there.  you just always do!)